# the lightest js/css to give visual feedback to the user that the SPA is loading/initializing

Tags: javascript, css, html

In my SPA (Single Page App) the first page is ultra-light in content. It simply loads dynamically a script which will then be responsible of populating the page.

It really looks like this:

```
<!docType HTML><html><body><div id='main'>initializing...</div>
<script>
var s = document.createElement("script"),
    t = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];

s.src="main.js";
t.parentNode.insertBefore(s, t);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is: 
By adding the smallest amount of javascript code or (maybe some inlined css style) can I make my "initializing..." string a bit more animated* ...

note: no third party allowed since that would delay the loading anyway...

*By a more animated 
I intend something like this

```
loading.     (immediately)
loading..    (500ms later)
loading...   (1s later)
loading..    (1500ms later)
```

hopefully you get the gist...

Comment: you want to move the text? or simulate animation like L LO LOA LOAD...???

Comment: @jordiCastilla yes, anything like that... I will edit my answer to make it more obvious

Comment: Sounds like you'd be better off asking on code golf

Comment: Interesting doctype, headtag and double scripttag opening.

Comment: @Klors harsh...and not sure why... wonder what type of questions you ask on stackoverflow

Comment: @Jonathan point taken. Made the amendments. Except for head which is really not required.

Comment: @Zo72 I'm not sure why you think I'm being harsh? Have you looked at code golf? You've got a challenge to produce a simple animation using the smallest amount of HTML, JavaScript or CSS possible. There are many potential solutions and you don't have some example code or technique that you're having issues with.

Comment: Yeah, this probably is code golf.   I've got mine down to 163^w161 bytes, BTW :)

Comment: @Alnitak nah, you're adding an html element so you should add 23 to that result, I still win the code gulf, even if your code is better, it's also ECMAscript 6 no?

Comment: @Zo72 `head` tag really is required

Comment: @Kaiido True, there is that extra element. The code doesn't even require ES3 though, let alone ES6.  Oh, and mine is bidirectional ;-)

Comment: @Klors LOL I thought code golf was a made up site...

Comment: @Jonathan head is not required. we are on html5 these days

Comment: @Zo72 nah, [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) is its full name on StackExchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is mine, 156 chars, you can stop it with `clearInterval(l)` in your external js file.

```js
var x=0;var l=setInterval(function(){x=(x+1)%4;var d ='',i=0;while(i<x){i++;d+='.';}document.getElementById('main').innerHTML='initializing'+d;},500);
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

expanded:

```
var x = 0;
var l = setInterval(function() {
  x = (x + 1) % 4;
  var d = '',
    i = 0;
  while (i < x) {
    i++;
    d += '.';
  }
  document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = 'initializing' + d;
}, 500);
```

Comment: Nah, fails on two points - requires external stop code, and leaks global variables all over the place ;-)

Comment: @Alnitak You're right and That's also why I upvoted yours even if you create a new html element :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's mine - it relies on an extra span with ID "dot" inside the "div".  I've deliberately avoided CSS animations so as to maintain greatest browser compatibility:

```
(function() {
    var dir = 1, s = '';
    (function loop() {
        var d = document.getElementById('dot');
        if (d) {
            var l = s.length;
            if (l > 2 || l < 1) dir = 1 - dir;
            s = dir ? s + '.' : s.substring(0, l - 1);
            d.innerHTML = s;
            setTimeout(loop, 500);
        }
    })();
})();
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/6x2qh9mh/1/

As soon as you remove the element "dot" from the DOM the loop will terminate.

Here's the same code minified (with some code tricks, to help):

```
+function(){var e,d=1,s='...',l=0;+function r(){if(e=document.getElementById('dot'))
{l+=d?1:-1;e.innerHTML=s.substr(0,l);d^=!(l%3);setTimeout(r,500);}}()}();
```

Comment: looks good... I was thinking something along those lines... might pick your answers unless somebody comes with something better

Comment: Hehe, like the minified one

Answer (score 0):

this is simple loader using css :

```
<style>
#squaresWaveG{
position:relative;
width:240px;
height:29px}

.squaresWaveG{
position:absolute;
top:0;
background-color:#000000;
width:29px;
height:29px;
-moz-animation-name:bounce_squaresWaveG;
-moz-animation-duration:0.8s;
-moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-moz-animation-direction:linear;
-webkit-animation-name:bounce_squaresWaveG;
-webkit-animation-duration:0.8s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-webkit-animation-direction:linear;
-ms-animation-name:bounce_squaresWaveG;
-ms-animation-duration:0.8s;
-ms-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-ms-animation-direction:linear;
-o-animation-name:bounce_squaresWaveG;
-o-animation-duration:0.8s;
-o-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-o-animation-direction:linear;
animation-name:bounce_squaresWaveG;
animation-duration:0.8s;
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
animation-direction:linear;
}

#squaresWaveG_1{
left:0;
-moz-animation-delay:0.32s;
-webkit-animation-delay:0.32s;
-ms-animation-delay:0.32s;
-o-animation-delay:0.32s;
animation-delay:0.32s;
}

#squaresWaveG_2{
left:30px;
-moz-animation-delay:0.4s;
-webkit-animation-delay:0.4s;
-ms-animation-delay:0.4s;
-o-animation-delay:0.4s;
animation-delay:0.4s;
}

#squaresWaveG_3{
left:60px;
-moz-animation-delay:0.48s;
-webkit-animation-delay:0.48s;
-ms-animation-delay:0.48s;
-o-animation-delay:0.48s;
animation-delay:0.48s;
}

#squaresWaveG_4{
left:90px;
-moz-animation-delay:0.56s;
-webkit-animation-delay:0.56s;
-ms-animation-delay:0.56s;
-o-animation-delay:0.56s;
animation-delay:0.56s;
}

#squaresWaveG_5{
left:120px;
-moz-animation-delay:0.64s;
-webkit-animation-delay:0.64s;
-ms-animation-delay:0.64s;
-o-animation-delay:0.64s;
animation-delay:0.64s;
}

#squaresWaveG_6{
left:150px;
-moz-animation-delay:0.72s;
-webkit-animation-delay:0.72s;
-ms-animation-delay:0.72s;
-o-animation-delay:0.72s;
animation-delay:0.72s;
}

#squaresWaveG_7{
left:180px;
-moz-animation-delay:0.8s;
-webkit-animation-delay:0.8s;
-ms-animation-delay:0.8s;
-o-animation-delay:0.8s;
animation-delay:0.8s;
}

#squaresWaveG_8{
left:210px;
-moz-animation-delay:0.88s;
-webkit-animation-delay:0.88s;
-ms-animation-delay:0.88s;
-o-animation-delay:0.88s;
animation-delay:0.88s;
}

@-moz-keyframes bounce_squaresWaveG{
0%{
background-color:#000000;
}

100%{
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce_squaresWaveG{
0%{
background-color:#000000;
}

100%{
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

}

@-ms-keyframes bounce_squaresWaveG{
0%{
background-color:#000000;
}

100%{
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

}

@-o-keyframes bounce_squaresWaveG{
0%{
background-color:#000000;
}

100%{
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

}

@keyframes bounce_squaresWaveG{
0%{
background-color:#000000;
}

100%{
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

}

</style>
<div id="squaresWaveG">
<div id="squaresWaveG_1" class="squaresWaveG">
</div>
<div id="squaresWaveG_2" class="squaresWaveG">
</div>
<div id="squaresWaveG_3" class="squaresWaveG">
</div>
<div id="squaresWaveG_4" class="squaresWaveG">
</div>
<div id="squaresWaveG_5" class="squaresWaveG">
</div>
<div id="squaresWaveG_6" class="squaresWaveG">
</div>
<div id="squaresWaveG_7" class="squaresWaveG">
</div>
<div id="squaresWaveG_8" class="squaresWaveG">
</div>
</div>
```

[More](http://cssload.net/)

Comment: I am using spa in which I use a gif image.

Comment: @PushkeyYadav thanks ... but it does look kind of way too many bytes

Comment: as for the gif image... clearly loading a gif might take way too long

Comment: I use gif that is 800 byte in size. @Zo72 you have to compromise. if you want a gif image http://www.ajaxload.info/